# What do these different formatting elements of Hebrew texts mean in Sefaria?

Tags: writing-printing, text

I am interested in gathering Hebrew texts in electronic form and what better resource than [sefaria.org](https://www.sefaria.org/texts). However, upon examining their [source](https://github.com/Sefaria/Sefaria-Export/tree/master/json), I notice some modern "English" or Latin writing system conventions used in the Hebrew texts, and wonder if I can get rid of them or change them to make them be more close to what the original texts would have looked like.

I understand that the [Niqqud](https://reformedreader.wordpress.com/2014/09/22/a-brief-history-of-hebrew-vowels/) was added around the middle ages, and many of the Hebrew texts on Sefaria were written around or since that time. "English" punctuation was invented around or slightly after that time as well. So any of this punctuation stuff is obviously probably not part of the actual text. What I would like is to remove or change these modern things so the text is more natural and less full or extraneous stuff.

Here are some examples:

**[הקדמה](https://www.sefaria.org/Baal_Shem_Tov%2C_Introduction.12?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)**: There are quotes here, single quotes `'` and double quotes `"`.

```
ואמרו הצדיקים הקדושים, כי מן זמן התגלות הבעל שם טוב הקדוש התחיל התנוצצות המשיח, והענין בודאי הוא אמת לאמתו, על פי מה דאיתא בספר הקדוש תולדות יעקב יוסף פ' וישב רל"ג ע"א, ומובא לקמן בספר זה בפרשת לך אות ב', כי סוד המשיח הוא סוד הדעת, וע"ש בהגה ג', וזה מובן על פי פשוטו גם כן, כי כן כתב הרמב"ם בפרק ט' מהלכות תשובה הלכה ב', וזה לשונו, ומפני זה נתאוו כל ישראל נביאיהם וחכמיהם לימות המשיח וכו', לפי שבאותן הימים תרבה הדעה והחכמה והאמת, שנאמר (ישעיהו י״א:ט׳) כי מלאה האם דעה את ה' וכו' ע"ש, ולקמן פ' שמות אות ט"ז העתקתי מס' תולדות יעקב יוסף סוף פ' וישלח, שזה היה ענין גאולת מצרים, מה שנתגלה הדעת על ידי משה רבינו עליו השלום, ובגאולה העתידה יתגלה הדעת ביתר שאת ויתר עוז, כי זה הדעת שנתגלה במצרים נקרא דעת דנוקבא, ובגאולה העתידה במהרה בימינו יתגלה דעת דדכורא ע"ש היטב.
```

**[בראשית, א׳:א׳](https://www.sefaria.org/Be%27er_Mayim_Chaim%2C_Genesis.1.1?lang=he)**: There are "small" parenthesized sections, also with quotes, like `<small>(תהלים ק\"ד, כ\"ד)</small>`.

```
<b>וכל</b> זה הוא עבור מה שידוע מזוה\"ק ומכתבי האר\"י ז\"ל אשר כל בריאת העולמות עליונים ותחתונים הכל נבראו בכח בחינת מדת החכמה בסוד הכתוב <small>(משלי ג', י\"ט)</small> ה' בחכמה יסד ארץ ואומר <small>(תהלים ק\"ד, כ\"ד)</small> מה רבו מעשיך ה' כולם בחכמה עשית, ופירוש כולם בחכמה עשית, כאמור, שכל הבריאה כולה מראש ועד סוף כולם נכללו בבחינת מדה הזו, וכולם שואפים שפעם וחיותם וכל הנצרך להם הכל ממדה הזו, והיא היתד גדול שהכל תלוי בה ונקראת כלל הכוללת כל הפרטים שתחתיה כי היא נקראת בחינת הראש כמאמר הכתוב <small>(שם קי\"א, י')</small> ראשית חכמה וגו', ולכן כל האברים נכללין בה. צא ולמד מה שכתוב בסידור האר\"י ז\"ל <small>(בכוונת ראש השנה)</small>, וזה לשונו: נודע שעולם הכתר בכל מקום שהוא הוא טמיר וגנוז ואף שנקרא ראש הוא בסוד הנעלם, ועיקר הראש הוא החכמה שנקרא ראשית דכתיב <small>(שם)</small> ראשית חכמה וכו' והכתר נעלם בתוכו בסוד כי עמך מקור חיים, והוא סוד א' שבמלת ראש כמבואר בזוה\"ק והוא ראש אל כל המוחין וכולל כולם דכתיב כולם בחכמה עשית וכו'. עד כאן. הרי לפניך שגם בחינת הכתר שהוא למעלה ממנה נכלל בה, ומכל שכן מה שלמטה ממנה.
```

**[שער](https://www.sefaria.org/Beit_Aharon)**: There are some bold and "big" things here, such as `<big><strong>ר' אהרן</strong></big>`. It's hard to see on Sefaria but in the raw source you can see it.

```
<b>י</b>שמחו <b>ה</b>לבבות <b>ו</b>יגילו <b>ה</b>נפשות נפשות ישראל החוסים בצל כנפיו של הקב"ה אשר קרבת אלקים יחפצון. דורשי ה' רודפי צדק דרשו מעל ספר ה' ותמצאו חפץ ה' בידכם יצליח. דרושים יקרים ונחמדים מהני תרי רבנן אשר על פי ספרי אמת הקדושים הם מיוסדים מאמרים אשר מפז ומפנינים יקרים. מה שיצא מפורש בקודש מדי שבת בשבתו ומדי רגל ברגל מפה קודש אדומו"ר הרב הגדול והקדוש אור ישראל כו' כקש"ת מו"ר <big><strong>ר' אהרן</strong></big> זצוקללה"ה זי"ע ועכ"י אמן. כפי גודל קדושתו האיר עינינו בתורתו ובתפילתו הזכה והמאירה רשום בכתב יושר דברי אמת אחד מני אלף מדבריו הקדושים ללבב וללהב לבבות ישראל לאהבת השי"ת ולדבקה בו. ולקבל חיות הקודש מדברי ציר נאמן לשולחו שלוחא דרחמנא אדומו"ר זצוקללה"ה בן לאותו סבא קדישא בוצינא דנהורא הרב המפורסם בקדושה ובטהרה כו' מו"ר <big><strong>ר' אשר</strong></big> זצוקללה"ה זיע"א בנו של הרב הצדיק האלקי מלאך אלקים קדוש ונורא אשר זכה וזיכה את הרבים כו' מו"ר <big><strong>ר' אהרן</strong></big> זצוקללה"ה זכותם יעמוד לנו בזה ובבא. ועשינו סניף למחברת הקודש כ"ק מאדומו"ר וכו' מרבינו <big><strong>אשר</strong></big> זצוקללה"ה אביו של אדומו"ר זצוקללה"ה. וכמה מאמרים המה בכתובים בכתב ידו הקדושה. גם כמה מכתבים קדושים וסדה"י של רבותינו הקדושים זצוקללה"ה שמסרו מידם הקדושה לקהל עדת ישורן שהסתופפו בצלם צלא דמהמנותא. והכתבים הקדושים של אדומו"ר זצוקללה"ה וכ"ק של אביו אדומו"ר זצוקלל"ה יחד היו אגודים וספונים ומוגהים בכתב ידו הקדושה של אדומו"ר ז"ל כמה הגהות וכמה ענינים. ומדי דברו בכ"ק האלו קרא שמם בפיו הקדוש <big><strong>בית אהרן</strong></big> כאשר יצא הדבר מפי זקנו הקדוש האלקי כו' מוהר"א מקארלין לבנו אדומו"ר כו' רבינו אשר זצוקללה"ה כאשר היה כבר עשר שנין שמע אביו זצ"ל מנגן הזמר יה אכסוף כו' בשבת קודש ושאל אותו היכן דתוב הזמר הזה והשיב בבית אהרן. ועטרת זקנים בני בנים ותפארת בנים אבותם. והתורה מחזרת על אכסניא שלה מעתה ועד עולם:
```

**[בן סירא](https://www.sefaria.org/Ben_Sira)**: There are bracketed things like this:

```
[כָּל חָכְמָה מֵיהֹוָה, וִעמּוֹ הִיא לְעוֹלָמִים.]
```

**[מעשה טוביה א׳](https://www.sefaria.org/Book_of_Tobit.1?lang=he)**: Here are more parentheses...

```
זה ספר טובי בן טוביאל בן חננאל (בן אריאל) בן גביאל בן עשאל בן ננתיאל ממטה נפתלי (אשר הגלה משומרון עם הגולה אשר הגלתה בימי הושע בן אלה) אשר הגלה בימי שלמנאסר מלך אשור והוא היה מתושבי עיר נפתלי אשר בגליל על גבול ימה:
```

There are also some places where you see `(?)` and where hyphens `-` are used between words, and some things are in italics.

- Can the bold and italics and big and small be removed? Is it encoding anything important?
- Can the quotes be changed to something else or removed?
- Can the things in brackets and parentheses be removed from the texts, or are they important parts of it?
- Can the hyphens be replaced with something else?

Basically, what needs to remain in the final text to keep it clean and uncluttered with "modern" or "English" stuff and metadata?

Comment: This is very likely out of scope for this site since the question is on Sefaria, not on Judaism. But did you try asking them directly (hello@sefaria.org)? They are usually very responsive

Comment: @mbloch While this is partly about Sefaria's encoding, a good chunk of this is about how Jewish texts tend to be formatted, which seems a topic well-suited for this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to parse texts whose format you don't understand sounds like a recipe for disaster. Complicating the matter, Sefaria's library includes texts from many different eras, with different formatting conventions. But to briefly answer your questions:

- **Quotes:** Single and double quotes are often used instead of `׳` and `״` for abbreviations. Some texts will use modern quotation marks to set off quotations, just like in English.
- **Parentheses/Brackets:** In many cases, parentheses are used to indicate text that someone thought was mistaken, and brackets are used to indicate text that the printer thought should be inserted (sometimes instead of the parenthetical words). In other texts, parentheses are used for parenthetical comments, like in English, and in other texts, brackets are used to set off more technical comments, or longer digressions.
- **Bold/Italic:** Bold text is common in commentaries to set off quoted text from the text in question from the commentary. I'm not sure about italics.
- **Font sizes:** Smaller font size is sometimes used to indicate a citation (often Biblical). This is usually unnecessary, but can be a nice graphical feature. Larger font can be used as the bold text is used, and sometimes in conjunction.
- **Hyphens:** Some dashes might be used as they're used in English. Sometimes a hyphen will be used instead of `־`.

And there are many more uses of each of these tools than I listed above.

Comment: Similarly, Koren likes to use one Hebrew font for biblical quotations and a different font for rabbinic text.